# call a function attached to custom button on onload of CRM Form

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to add a function to each and every entity on save event. 
For that I have added a button to application ribbon , so it will be shown on each and every entity and attached my function to it.
But now I have to add this function to `onsave` of form without clicking the button.
Here is my function:-

```
function test()
{
   alert("hello");
   Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(addMethod);
}
function addMethod()
{
   alert("i am added");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was just add a enable rule to my button command.

Problem: Need to replace a generic plugin registered on each and every entity update event with a javascript function.

Solution:

1. Created a solution with my custom webresource and Application ribbon.
2. With the help of Ribbon Workbench added a button to entity form.(Button added to application Ribbon is added to each and every entity)
3. Added a enable rule to return false always to hide my button :

   ```
   function enablerule()
   {
       Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(addMethod);
       return false;
   }

   function addmethod()
   {
       //my logic
   }
   ```

and that logic replaced a generic plugin server side code with  client side code :)

I know this is not a supported way, but I had to do anyway. I told my Team Lead about it, but he wanted it in any way. So, please, no comments on that.